# How can I filter the elements in the list by certain criteria and then change their properties with Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have `List`, for example:

```
    public class User
        {    
            public string Name { get; set;}
            public bool IsShow { get; set;}
        }

    List<User> myList = new List<User>();
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser2", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser3", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "BUser", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser4", IsShow = true});
```

How can I filter the elements in the list by certain criteria and then change their properties with Linq?

I filter the elements:

```
myList.AsEnumerable().Where(u => u.Name.Contains("/" + F + "/");
```

So, I want property `IsShow = true` for `"FUser"`, `"FUser2"`, `"FUser3"`, `"FUser4"` and `IsShow = false` for `BUser`.

It's possible with Linq, without cycle?

Comment: What, exactly, is the meaning of *without cycle*?

Comment: I mean without cycle in code, I can select a needed elements with Linq and then in cycle foreach() define properties, but I wanted Linq to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void Main()
{
    List<User> myList = new List<User>();
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser2", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser3", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "BUser", IsShow = true});
    myList.Add(new User(){Name = "FUser4", IsShow = true});

    // the magic happens here
    var results = myList.Select(p=> new User { Name = p.Name, IsShow=p.Name.First()=='F'});
}
    public class User
        {    
            public string Name { get; set;}
            public bool IsShow { get; set;}
        }

// Define other methods and classes here
```

Answer (score 3):

How about `List<T>'`s ForEach method (which is not actually part of Linq):

```
myList.ForEach(u => { u.IsShow = u.Name.Contains("..."); });
```

Note that Linq is about *querying* data, not modifying it. (Language Integrated **Query**)

Comment: note that you simply could use `(u => u.IsShow = u.Name.Contains("..."))`

Comment: Thank you! It's a cycle, but this solution is very suitable for me, I just wanted to reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

> It's possible with Linq, without cycle?

This kind of question gets asked a lot.  What you mean by "without cycle" is - without enumerating the collection.  I think it's a prayer that Linq.Enumerable can somehow use a magically generated index into your list to find what you're looking for without looking at the whole list.  Unfortunately, this is not the case.  Linq.Enumerable doesn't have magical indexes into your list, it works by enumerating the list - the same as a foreach loop you might write.

So - the answer to the question is "No".

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I know that Linq use loop, but I wanted Linq to do this transparently for me. I understand you, thank.

Answer (score 1):

Well outside your question when you create your list you should use collection initializer. Also, set the Ienumerable here.

```
IEnumerable<User> myList = new List<User>
      {
         new User() {Name = "FUser", IsShow = true},
         new User() {Name = "FUser2", IsShow = true},
         new User() {Name = "FUser3", IsShow = true},
         new User() {Name = "BUser", IsShow = true},
         new User() {Name = "FUser4", IsShow = true}
      };
```

Then to do what you are asking you would have to do:

```
string parameter = "F";
foreach (var s in myList.Where(s => s.Name.Contains == parameter))
        {
            s.IsShow = true;
        }
```

or

```
string parameter = "BUser";
foreach (var s in myList.Where(s => s.Name == parameter))
        {
            s.IsShow = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually change the source list's object using following code:

```
List<User> myList = new List<User>();
myList.Add(new User() { Name = "FUser", IsShow = true });
myList.Add(new User() { Name = "FUser2", IsShow = true });
myList.Add(new User() { Name = "FUser3", IsShow = true });
myList.Add(new User() { Name = "BUser", IsShow = true });
myList.Add(new User() { Name = "FUser4", IsShow = true });

myList
    .Where(user => user.Name.StartsWith("F"))
    .Select(user => 
    { 
        user.IsShow = true; 
        return user; 
    });
```

That saves you extra 'cycles' when you would loop the result list using a foreach statemtent.